# Magic Square Method needs to output if it is a magic square and the sum of rows and columns

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on an assignment that takes a data file with a number matrix and determines if it is a magic square.  If it is then it also needs to report the sum of the rows and columns.  With the output:

The matrix is a magic square.
The sum of all the rows and columns is 34.

I'm not sure how to go about this with one method, I feel like its asking me to return 2 values.  The closest I have came is by adding a System.out.println with the sum at the end of my method when it returns true.

But the issue with that is that my output is backwords:

The sum of all the rows and columns is 34.
The matrix is a magic square.

How do I get the sum when I've only been asked to create one method?  Below is my code, the instructor gave the bottom 3 methods so I'm only concerned with the first 2.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class chp8magic
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int matrix[][] = initMatrix();
        printData(matrix); 

        if (isMagic(matrix)) {
            System.out.println("The matrix is a magic square.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Not a magic square");
        }
    }

    public static boolean isMagic(int[][] mat)
    {
        int n = mat.length;
        int nSquare = n*n;
        int M = (n*n*(n*n+1)/2)/n;
        int sumRow = 0, sumColoumns = 0, sumPriDiag = 0, sumSecDiag = 0;
        boolean[] flag = new boolean[n*n];

        for(int row = 0; row < n; row++){

            sumRow = 0;
            sumColoumns = 0;

            for(int col = 0; col < n; col++)
            {
                if( mat[row][col] < 1 || mat[row][col] > nSquare )
                    return false;
                if(flag[mat[row][col]-1] == true) 
                    return false;

                flag[mat[row][col]-1] = true;
                sumRow += mat[row][col];
                sumColoumns += mat[col][row];
            }
            sumPriDiag += mat[row][row];
            sumSecDiag += mat[row][n-row-1];
            if(sumRow!=M || sumColoumns!=M)
                return false;
        }
        if(sumPriDiag!=M || sumSecDiag!=M) 
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public static int[][] initMatrix()
    {
        int matrix[][];
        Scanner filein = null;

        try {

            filein = new Scanner(new File("matrix.txt"));
            int numRows = Integer.parseInt(filein.nextLine());
            matrix = new int[numRows][];
            parseData(matrix, filein);
            filein.close();

            return matrix;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            if(filein != null)
                filein.close();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void parseData(int matrix[][], Scanner in)
    {
        for(int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++)
        {
            String splitLine[] = in.nextLine().split(" ");
            matrix[r] = new int[splitLine.length];

            for(int c = 0; c < matrix[r].length; c++){
                matrix[r][c] = Integer.parseInt(splitLine[c]);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printData(int matrix[][])
    {
        for(int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++){
            for(int c = 0; c < matrix[r].length; c++){
                System.out.print(matrix[r][c] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Which two methods do you need help with? If you been to return two values then you should change to return type to an array.

Comment: Could you put the print statements inside your `isMagic()` method instead of in `main()`?

Comment: @gla3dr - I disagree with this request. An efficient programmer practices cohesion and knows how to compartmentalize and limit his functions/methods to a few powerful yet simple tasks, with a few exceptions here and there. The print statement does not belong there because lets say that OP wanted to later come back and create some more methods that check for magic squares? but lets say they aren't supposed to print, but instead just perform logic operations, a large part of  the idea of boolean methods/functions: check if something is true or not, and return.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you just need to do:

```
System.out.println("is magic: " + isMagic);
System.out.ptintln("sum: " + sum);
```

However this is not really returning the values, just printing them. To return two values there are several options. You could return an object:

```
public class MagicSquareProperties {

    private boolean magic;
    private int sum;

    public MagicSquareProperties(boolean magic, int sum) {
        this.magic = magic;
        this.sum = sum;
    }

    public boolean isMagic() {
        return magic;
    }

    public int getSum() {
        return sum;
    }
}

// now to return both values: return new MagicSquareProperties(true, 34);
```

But in my opinion the best solution would be the following:

1. Create a class MagicSquare.
2. Add property declarations (e.g. private int sum).
3. Add a constructor, for example MagicSquare(File file), this constructor reads the file and populates the properties.
4. Add getters and setters if needed (e.g. getSum())
5. Execute the main method in another class and call new MagicSquare(...) to create a magic square object. Afterwards you can call the getters on the object whenever you need the value.

Comment: My issue that this is to be accomplished by creating and using one method.  I already have created a method that will give me the sum so that isn't really my issue.  I would have to confirm I'm 99 percent sure that the method is to be called as that's the way he wants everything.

Comment: Yes, the problem is probably, that the exercise isn't specific enough. I don't know what you mean by "the method is to be called", do you have to implement an Interface? After reading it again, I think you need to do is to either print: "The matrix is not a magic square" or "The matrix is a magic square. The sum of all rows and columns is 34".